# GoLang HTTP GET - 400 Bad Request

Tags: http, go, get, bad-request

I am making HTTP GET call using below GoLang code:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", getUrl, nil)
//req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "br")
response, _ := client.Do(req)
```

Receiving error response:

```
<html>
     <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
     <body bgcolor="white">
          <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
          <hr><center>nginx</center>
     </body>
</html>
```

To print above error response, I am using simple:

```
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
log.Println(string(data))
```

When I pick up getUrl and execute simply in Chrome browser, it returns success response:

```
{"message":"SUCCESS","errorcode": "0" ,"errormessage":""}
```

Chrome request header:

```
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:api.pepipost.com
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
```

Chrome response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 18 Feb 2018 11:01:28 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy:3.1
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Server1:Region-US
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Please help.

Comment: please post more code what your are doing to fetch the response. Or you are using debugger to check response.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, added in post -> data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

Comment: you should be more specific in your post. Your code is simple. And It is hard to analyze here what is going wrong. Nothing seems wrong in your posted code

Comment: Sorry Himanshu, problem is now resolved, I have posted self answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, I found the answer. Earlier I use to create big getUrl by appending all parameters to it. After doing below, the problem was resolved.

```
q := req.URL.Query()
q.Add("key", "value")
req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
```